# Read input and output the results out

Tags: python, input

How do i code out in python such that when user type 3, system will output 3 ^?
For example,

```
userinput: 3
system: ^^^
userinput: 4
system: ^^^^
```

am i supposed to use a for loop and loop over it? Im very new to python, please help. thanks!

Comment: `print '^'*int(raw_input())` for python2 and `print('^'*int(input()))` for python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in its very simplest form:

```
from_input = raw_input()
print int(from_input) * '^'
```

This will parse the incoming string to integer.
However, to note here is that if you put anything else than a string that can be parsed to an it will raise a `ValueError`.

A safer approach would then be

```
from_input = raw_input()
try:
   int(from_input) * '^'
except ValueError:
   print "Can't cast {0} to int".format(from_input)
```

Comment: You may want to change the name of the variable; `input` is also a function, which would be made inaccessible after this code.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks, sometimes I forget myself! :)

Comment: @limelights also it isn't *casting* it's *parsing* the input to an int.

Comment: so "from_input" is a variable that will takes in whatever the user has input in the raw_input()?

Comment: @user2353680 yeah, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

First,check the input.
Then

```
print('^'*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 (In Python2, you should use raw_input instead of input)

```
>>> x = input("userinput: ")
userinput: 4
>>> print("{:^^{}}".format("", x))
^^^^
```

Or as a program

```
x = input("userinput: ")
print("{:^^{}}".format("", x))
```